# EWS call make memory leaks?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, memory-leaks, exchangewebservices

I have a basic test where I'm only trying to get 50 message IDs by using ExchangeService.FindItems.
And because I've seen this leak, I've made a project to try to highlight it.

In this project, I only have a loop function printing the memory usage before and after the call of the function and the delta between both.

here is my code:

```
        static private bool AutodiscoverCallBack(string url)
        {
            return url.ToLower().StartsWith("https://");
        }

        static void getId(ExchangeService accountExchangeService)
        {
            ItemView view = new ItemView(50);
            
            view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId, ItemSchema.DateTimeCreated);
            view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
            view.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow;
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = accountExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);
        }

        static void loop(ExchangeService accountExchangeService)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                Console.WriteLine("press a key to run the test");
                Console.ReadKey();
                long aMem = currentProcess.PrivateMemorySize64;
                Console.WriteLine("memory before function:" + aMem);
                getId(accountExchangeService);
                currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                long bMem = currentProcess.PrivateMemorySize64;
                Console.WriteLine("memory after function:" + bMem);
                long delta = bMem - aMem;
                Console.WriteLine("delta memory: " + delta.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExchangeService accountExchangeService = new ExchangeService();
            accountExchangeService.EnableScpLookup = true;
            accountExchangeService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test@outlook.fr", "Password");
            accountExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl("test@outlook.fr", AutodiscoverCallBack);
            loop(accountExchangeService);
        }
```

and I have this kind of output:

```
press a key to run the test
memory before function:18644992
memory after function:20017152
delta memory: 1372160

press a key to run the test
memory before function:20008960
memory after function:20271104
delta memory: 262144

press a key to run the test
memory before function:20336640
memory after function:20598784
delta memory: 262144

press a key to run the test
memory before function:20664320
memory after function:20930560
delta memory: 266240
```

Comment: From my overall experience EWS - piece of garbage. Not sure about your case, but it indeed: leaks memory on reads, especially if error occurs (it leaks memory in its own unmanaged memory, god know why), NOT thread safe (so be caution) complete garbage at syncing custom attributes on mails/folders, library functionality is scattered across outlook specific libraries and EWS ones. So - don't use EWS. Use simple protocol wrappers (IMAP, POP3).